# Traduire « duelling »

Tags: traduction, anglais, participe-présent

Je cherchais à traduire « *Duelling Uilleann Pipes* » et je ne trouve rien de satisfaisant pour *duelling*. La forme la plus proche en français serait *se battant en duel*, mais c'est un peu verbeux, et anglicir en *duellantes* serait un peu <s>dégueulasse</s> inesthétique.

Y a-t-il un autre verbe de sens proche dont je pourrais utiliser le participe présent ?

<sub>Le lecteur intéressé pourra se reporter à [[YOU01]](http://youtu.be/Is5DF8q25q0) pour davantage de détails.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pourquoi utiliser forcément le participe présent, alors qu'il sera lourd ? ***« Un duel de cornemuses »*** (bon, j'ai pas la finesse de traduction de *Uilleann Pipes*, désolé) sera très clair… J'ai déjà participé à un *duel d'orchestres*, le terme n'a choqué personne.

Comment: Assez littéralement, "un duel d'orchestre(s?)" serait un *concerto*, non ;-)

Comment: @Dave Oui, c'est bien ça la différence entre les faux-frères *duo* et *duel* ;-)

Comment: Ca depend si les musiciens/orchestres jouent ensemble ou l'un contre l'autre ^.^

Comment: *Un duel de cornemuses irlandaises?*

Answer (score 3):

Ta traduction littérale initiale (*Cornemuses se battant en duel*) était juste, mais comme tu le soulignes, un peu lourde. De plus, un duel n'implique pas directement un combat, mais plus généralement un affrontement. On pourrait alors faire le choix d'omettre le verbe d'action pour obtenir une version plus concise (et, d'une certaine manière, plus juste) : **Cornemuses en duel**

Answer (score 2):

Pour fournir une alternative au duel: dans le milieu du théâtre on parle souvent de *match d'impro* (visation).

Comment: Mais ça prend des théâtreux pour comprendre, un peu, non ? (Le public inaverti parlera facilement de « spectacle d'impro ».) Et puis, ça perd le dynamisme du duel, trouvé-je.

Answer (score 2):

Pour transposer *duel* et garder la structure de la phrase originale :

> - Affrontements de cornemuses
> - Radio-crochets de cornemuse (si les défaillants sont immédiatement exclus de la scène)
> - Les rencontres de cornemuses (pour un festival par exemple)

et aussi très proche de la notion de *duel*, selon le contexte et ce que l'on veut mettre en avant :

> - Assauts de cornemuse
> - Joutes de cornemuse
> - Compétitions de cornemuses
> - Combats de cornemuses

Comment: C'est un terme qui date un peu, mais qui parait tout à fait pertinent. Par contre, d'après ce que j'ai pu trouver sur Wikipédia, le *Radio-* vient de radiodiffusion, et a priori il est donc superflu ici.